# Linking Python to AppleScript for datetime

Tags: python, datetime, arguments, applescript, bridge

Basically my goal is to be able to use a start and end date from Python for arguments in this AppleScript..

```
import commands

cmd = """osascript -e 'tell application "Calendar"
    set all_calendars to title of every calendar

    if "SimpleCal" is in all_calendars then
        set primary_calendar to "SimpleCal"
    else
        create calendar with name "SimpleCal"
        set primary_calendar to "SimpleCal"
    end if

    set start_date_mod to date %s
    set end_date_mod to date "Wednesday, August 14, 2013 at 8:10:00 PM"

    tell calendar primary_calendar
        set new_event to make new event at end with properties {description:"Imported with App", summary:"event_type", location:"", start date: start_date_mod, end date:end_date_mod}
        tell new_event
            make new display alarm at end with properties {trigger interval:-5}
        end tell
    end tell

end tell
'""" % ("Wednesday, August 14, 2013 at 8:00:00 PM")
status = commands.getoutput(cmd)
print status
```

Comment: you could try to add quotes: `set start_date_mod to date "%s"`. To convert a datetime object to a string, you could use [`.strftime()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime).

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what it was.. I'd like to mark that as an advisor, can you put it in the answer area?

Answer (score 1):

Use strftime to convert the python date into a suitable string that Applescript can coerce into a date object:

```
import datetime

>>> AS_DATE_FORMAT = "%A, %B %d, %Y %I:%M:%S %p"
>>> right_now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> date_string = right_now.strftime(AS_DATE_FORMAT)
'Wednesday, August 14, 2013 11:01:10 AM'
```

Then, in your AppleScript section, you just add the date:

```
"set start_date_mod to date %s
set end_date_mod to date " + date_string
```